# MySQL Workbench not opening on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I have downloaded the no-install portable version of Workbench. When I run the exe file (on Windows XP), nothing happens. Does it need some MySQL running? I think it's standalone, right? I have XAMPP for MySQL. Any dependency etc?

Comment: You need to install Net Framework 4.0 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)  in order to run MySql Workbench-> see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-requirements-software.html

Comment: When you use the MySQL installer it will not only check for all prerequisites but also lead you to the download locations for them. So it's especially easy to set this up.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the installer. Which OP (and me) apparently do not want to use.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to install the following in order to run the current version of MySQL Workbench:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019

See: [dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-requirements-software.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-requirements.html) 
.

Comment: This fixed it for me. It amazes me that there's not sort of error message, the process starts and then stops are 10 seconds or so.

Comment: If you run against this problem in a more recent times ... make sure you download the 2013 versions instead: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784 (!)

Comment: My system already have Net Framework and MS Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package but still not able to open.

Comment: @Dhirender "Already has .net framework" and "Already has .net framework 4.0" are two different things. You also should've installed Visual C++ 2010 to run the program. It's not enough to have VC++ 2015.

Comment: A newer link to the requirements when installing on Windows: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-windows.html#wb-installing-windows-requirements

Comment: worked for me, thanks , i used this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Important step - reinstall workbench after all prerequisites are in place.

Comment: this worked for me, I installed 2015 before as it was required while installation and that did not start the workbench. Then installed 2019 and it worked. Thanks

Comment: I have to install in the default c:\program files instead of d:\program files to get it working.

Answer (score 18):

Update 2020:

Unfortunately this is still happening:

1. Download [.NET 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search?q=net%20framework%204.0%20download) (My machine already had it.)
2. Download [Visual C++](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
3. As the above solution states. Download the [Mysql workbench
   installer](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/).

I still don't know why, it would allow me to install without checking for dependencies. I have become accustomed to this kind of behavior when I am installing any application and to not see it is annoying. I suppose I should leave this personal opinions out of my solution but I have had to install this multiple times and have comes across some kind of dependency issue.

Comment: MySQL Workbench wouldn't launch when installed on a fresh Windows 10 setup. I had to install a legacy version of MySQL Workbench and then use the inbuilt update feature version to install the latest version. That worked.

Comment: In my case, a previously working workbench stopped launching. Installing the Visual C++ Redistributable fixed it for me.

Comment: This! This works as far as 18 Feb 2020. No other solution listed worked. I already had C++ redist (from Visual Studio) and .Net as well (my visual studio had C# and C++). However Mysql Workbench refused to open, no window, no tab, nothing, double click and nothing happened at all. After installing the C++ redist, it opened within half a sec.

Comment: Downloading Visual C++ works for me (March 03, 2020).

Answer (score 8):

What works for me (workbench 64bit) is that I installed Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 
here is url:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

I installed both x86: vc_redist.x86.exe and x64: vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: Worked for me as well. Workbench 8.0.19

Comment: I only need to install `x64: vc_redist.x64.exe` and then it worked for me.  (MySql Workbench 8.0.19)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, i tried all solutions but nothing worked.

My SO is windows 7 x64, with all the  Redistributable Packages (x86,x64 / 2010,2013,2015)

The problem was that i tried to install the x64 workbench, but for some reason did not work (even my SO is x64).

so, the solution was download the x86 installer from : https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10 I browsed to %APPDATA%\MySQL\Workbench\ then deleted the **workbench_user_data.dat** file

Doing so lost my MySqlWorkbence settings but allowed MySqlWorkbence to open.

Comment: Deleting this file didnt worked for me, but deleting entire Workbench worked.

Comment: This and ending the MySQL WorkBench in task manager worked!

Answer (score 4):

There are two prerequisite requirements need to install MySql Workbench as follows.

1. .Net Framework 4.0
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

When `.Net Framework 4.0` does not exist your computer installation will be corrupted. But if `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010` does not exist your computer then you will continue the installation but cannot open MySql Workbench program. Sometimes you will need `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013` instead of `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010`. So I recommend to install `Microsoft Visual C++ 2013`.

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: My system already have Net Framework and MS Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package but still not able to open.

Comment: Same problem here, started yesterday, installed everything but software does not start.

Answer (score 1):

As per the current setup on June, 2017
Here is the downloadable link for Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package : https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe

Hope this will help, who are struggling with the download link.

Note: This is with regards to MySQL Workbench 6.3.9

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled 8.0.19 (64) and installed 8.0.18 (64 bit) and now it Opens.

Answer (score 0):

it might be due to running of xampp or wampp server stop all services running and try to open mysql command line

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed more than just the Visual C++ Redistributable 2015.

I also needed what's at [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). It's confusing because the titles make it ambiguous as to whether you're downloading the (very heavy) Visual Studio or just Visual C++. In this case it only upgrades Visual C++, and MySQL Workbench launched after this install.

Answer (score 0):

You should have these two already installed in your system:

1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable
2. Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2

I did these two installations for MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE.

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions worked for, however setting compatibility to Vista worked and now the workbench opens again.

Answer (score 0):

**2022 case:**

My MySQL Workbench was working normally and from one moment it just didn't want to open anymore. I've lost almost half a day trying to fix it.

In folder `%APPDATA%\MySQL\` I had to delete the whole folder Workbench,
instead of deleting just `workbench_user_data.dat` file (which didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Given that there's so little on this on the web, I'll provide my answer despite this thread being over two years old: it's probably a no-brainer but run Workbench as Administrator (doh!)