# MYSQL Workbench 8.0.27 not opening on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've successfully installed MySQL 8.0.27 with Workbench 8.0.27 on Windows 10, but when I try to launch Workbench it's just not starting or even appears in task manager.
After googling around a bit I found that I have to install the following:

1. Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019.

so I download & installed them, still Workbench doesn't want to start!!!

**Things I've tried to do:**

- uninstall & reinstall Workbench version 8.0.27 & 8.0.18.
- restarting my computer
- installing visual studio 2013 (but on drive E and not C).
- installing a number of Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable including 2010, 2013 for both x64 & x86.
- installing Python 3.10 with adding it to PATH variable.

**Following Links didn't help:**

- [MySQL Workbench not opening on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673285/mysql-workbench-not-opening-on-windows)
- [MySQL Workbench is not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022625/mysql-workbench-is-not-opening)

Comment: Did you check the event viewer or the application logs to check for any issues reported there?

Comment: I couldn't manage to find where the log files are stored....

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html

Comment: I've seen this page before, but when I try to navigate to it windows says "Windows can't find "log path" Check the spelling and try again"  and that's because i couldn't find a folder called MySQL inside Roaming folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran

```
sfc /scannow
```

in CMD under Administrative privileges & it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/**

Install this first package installer in which you will get the whole package installer and also include workbench and co-related things.

Comment: I've downloaded a file with size 209 MB, but there is not any installer.exe . What should i do with this zip file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you downloaded the [Windows installer for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html) to install both the server and Workbench. You did not mention it in your question, so I want o ensure we have a common start point.

Python 3.10 changed a few things that might not work with MySQL Workbench 8.0.27. So, better go back to Python 3.9 for the time being.

If that still doesn't work we need to look at your WB log file.

Comment: Yes I've tried the offline & online installer for MySQL. And I've just tried installing Python 3.9 and 3.8 with adding python to PATH variable and it still not working, but I've noticed that I can connect to the Database through the cmd, and the directory for the logs should be C:/users/my_user/AppData/Roaming/MySql   but in my case it doesn't exist (there is no MySql inside the Roaming)